# Data Migration from different Databases different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, migration

I have a Db called Db1, and also I have a different Db called Db2. Db2 has no data. I want to migrate data from Db1 to Db2, but this two databases are not the same with each other. They include different tables, different column names.
Is there anyway to bind one or more tables or columns to other Db's tables columns to transport data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Integration Services
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to Move Data
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

[image]

Comment: my Db is too large and two database has two different table scripts